# Differences between std::vector and java.util.Vector

Tags: java, c++

In C++ i can insert an item into an arbitrary position in a vector, just like the code below:

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
vec.insert(vec.begin()+2,2);
vec.insert(vec.begin()+4,3);
```

In Java i can not do the same, i get an exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, code below:

```
Vector l5 = new Vector(10);
l5.add(0, 1);
l5.add(1, "Test");
l5.add(3, "test");
```

It means that C++ is better designed or is just a Java design decision ?
Why java use this approach ?

Comment: `Vector` is depricated in java, use `ArrayList` instead

Comment: Or maybe C++ is worse-designed.

Comment: @DaveNewton take that back haha

Comment: It just means you haven't read the java docs carefully.

Comment: @user814628: Dave is correct up to some level. In Java it is safely designed, since it is a safe high level language than C++. But I disagree with "worse-designed" statement, since Java derives from C++ and it widely follows C++ technologies. Anyway this question is all about techniques used in data structures.

Comment: another thing, someone has down voted this question, and I up voted it. Dear developers, there is no need of down voting questions :)

Comment: Where is Vector in Java deprecated? Not even in Java 10. It is just recommended for different purposes. Vector is thread-safe, ArrayList not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the C++ code:

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
```

You are creating a vector of **size 10**. So all indexes from 0 to 9 are valid afterwards.

In the Java code:

```
Vector l5 = new Vector(10);
```

You are creating an **empty** vector with an initial capacity of 10. It means the underlying array is of size 10 but the vector itself has the size 0.

It does not mean one is better designed than the other. The API is just different and this is not a difference that makes one better than the other.

Note that in Java it is now preffered to use `ArrayList`, which has almost the same API, but is not synchronized. If you want to find a bad design decision in Java's Vector, then this synchronization on every operation was probably one.

Therefore the best way to write an equivalent of the C++ initialization code in Java is :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    list.add(new Integer());
}
```

Comment: so the latter is akin to   `vec.reserve(10);`

Comment: In Java, you shouldn't use `Vector`, please refer to [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197). Instead, please recommend using `List<YourClass>` backed up with `ArrayList<YourClass>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I have seen people working with Java 1.4 and they need vector. But I agree with you 200% :)

Comment: @Yohan I've seend people using Vector in Java 1.4 but I still don't understand the main reason. If it was for *synchronized work*, well, they had started with a wrong design and didn't wanted to start making the changes to a better approach/design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yeah, agreed. But there are 2 main reasons. First one is outdated environment. Some work with old web containers with J2EE. J2EE is 100% OK, but they do not use the updated versions of J2EE (They dnt have to use JEE, they dnt use J2EE new versions). Second reason is people don't like to change. Some companies are there who work with Visual Studio 2000 LOL! So we have to expect the same for Java from them. These 2 are my personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc for [Vector.add(int, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) pretty clearly states that an IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown if the index is less than zero or greater than or equal to the size. The Vector type grows as needed, and the constructor you've used sets the initial capacity, which is different than the size. Please read the linked Javadoc to better understand how to use the Vector type. Also, we java developers typically use a List type, such as ArrayList in situations where you would generally use a std::vector in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Differences? You cannot compare how 2 languages do those. Normally `Vector` do use Stack data structure or LinkedList (or may be both). Which means, you put one item to the top, put another item on top of it, another item even on top of it, like wise. In LinkedList, it is bit different, you "pull" the value but the same thing. So in C++ it is better to use `push_back()` method.

C++ Vector objects are instantiated automatically. But in Java it is not, you have to fill it. I disagree with the way of filling it using `l5.add(1, "Test");`. Use `l5.add("test")`.

Since you asked differences, you can define your object in this way as well

```
 Vector a = new Vector();
```

That is without a type, in Java we call it without `Generics`. Possible since Java 1.6

Vector is now not widely used in Java. It has delays. We now move with `ArrayList` which is inside `List` interface.

**Edit**

variable names such as `l5` are widely used in C++. But Java community expects more meaningful variable names :)

Comment: This is not a discusion about variable names, is about data structures in different languages.

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva: It is a suggestion. It is up to you to take it or leave it. Anyway, stackoverflow is not for discussions.

Comment: Just a side note: Generics exist since Java 1.5